# Unable to format a string

Tags: python, python-2.7, formatting, string-formatting

I am trying to format a text. Below is my code.

```
str = """
    def services = {0}
    try {
        // try code block
    } finally {
        // finally code block
    }
""".format(json.dumps(services))
```

But I am getting following error.

```
Key ' // try code block ' has no corresponding argument
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with {{}}. Like

```
try {{
   // try block her
}}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need double curly braces around in the try catch part of the string as it is right now format is looking for extra arguments. Try `try {{ }}`.. so that the format will work properly.